# Matlab - plot; modify X-axis values without modifying graph

Tags: matlab, plot

The following examplary graph is created on a value storage from a loop (vector data plotted against matrix index). I would like to modify the values on the x-axis, in this case I would like to divide them by a hundred without changing the plot. Is there any easy way to do this ?

Furthermore i have similar graphs where i would like not just to divide/ or multiply the values but also to add or substract values without changing the actual plot.I thought of creating a second vector and to plot them against each other, but as I have a lot of different graphs I was wondering whether there is a GUI tool to help me with this ? Or maybe some easy line of code to change the index against which the vector is plotted.

[image]

Thankful for every advice!

Comment: "without changing the plot" - What exactly should be changed then? Only the tick labels of the plot? Or do you want to change the *plotted data* **without** changing the underlaying values of the original data?

Comment: only the tick labels of the x-axis

Comment: [http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292303](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292303)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the x-values of the plotted data instead of manually changing the tick-labels. This has the advantage that you can zoom-in and the ticks get adjusted properly. It can be easily achieved by using a handle to the plot, read the `XData` property and write it back with your desired modifications. Note that the values of `x` remain untouched and only the data of the plot itself gets changed.

```
% example data
y = linspace(-0.6,4.05,100)*1e8;
x = linspace(700,1100,100);

% plot figure
figure;                     % create a new figure
ph = plot(x,y);             % plot and store handle

% change x-values of plot
xp = get(ph,'XData');       % extract from plot using handle
xp = xp/100;                % modify x-data
set(ph,'XData',xp);         % write back to plot using handle
```

*Resulting plot:*

[image: result1]

---

The other option is to manually change the labels. This has the disadvantage that the originally modified ticks remain and won't be adjusted when you zoom in. So you won't get any additional ticks unless you write a callback function for the plot, which is more complicated than the proposed approach. Still, here is a way to change only the ticks:

```
xtick = get(gca,'XTick');
set(gca,'XTick',xtick,'XTickLabel',xtick/100);
```